# Gui clipboard not working

Tags: autohotkey

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
#SingleInstance force
; empty window sample

Gui, Show , w260 h100, Temmie Clipper
Gui, Add, Button, gINTRO ,Hoi
Gui, Add, Button, gBount ,Bount
Gui, Add, Button, gDog ,Dogresidu
return
INTRO:
{
clipboard = hOI!!! i'm temmie

}
Bount:
{
clipboard = giv temmie dogresidu... NOW!!!!

}

Dog:
{

clipboard = us tems are normally BOUNTS!




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are labels, not functions, so they will not return automatically. Therefore the execution always proceeds to the last instruction which is `clipboard = us tems are normally BOUNTS!`, if any button is pressed.

Change the syntax to:

```
INTRO:
    clipboard = hOI!!! i'm temmie
return
```

And do the same for labels: `Bount` and `Dog`.

Comment: Oh my gosh! Thank you sooo much!